# Lua for Wireshark: Tvp.new_real() doesn't exist?

Tags: lua, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

The documentation for Lua for Wireshark claims that the Tvp class has a new_real() method.
However, this method seems to not exist when I try to use it in my Lua script.
I'm using Wireshark 1.3.5 (latest dev version) for Windows x64.
Did the method get renamed? If so, to what? Is there a better support forum for this particular question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the function was moved into the ByteArray class -- you call ByteArray:tvb() rather than Tvb.real_new(byteArray) now.

Answer (score 0):

Very commonly if I am not sure what methods are available in a library I use the `pairs` function to print them out. I guess you could use the same approach with your problem.

```
for k, v in pairs(Tvp) do print(k, v) end
```

Comment: I tried that. The object is a userdata, not a table, so pairs doesn't work.